# nodejs send data to api axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios

Below is my nodejs configuration:

> ```
> const Tail = require('tail').Tail;
> const axios = require("axios");
>
> console.log("Watching...");
> var tail = new Tail("./nxerror.log");
> tail.watch()
> tail.on("line", data => {
> console.log("data changeed");
>   console.log(data);
> var username = 'Eve'
> var password = 'changeme'
>
> const body = {"action":"EventsRouter", "method":"add_event", "data": [{"summary":"test","device":"test","message":"msg","component":"testhost","severity":"5","evclasskey":"nxlog","evclass":"/nxlog/perf","monitor":"localhost"}],"type":"rpc","tid":2}
>
> var url = 'https://myurl.com/zport/dmd/evconsole_router';
>
>  axios({
>         method:'post',
>         url:url,
>         headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
>         data: body,
>         auth: {
>             username: username,
>             password: password
>         }
>     }).then(function (response) {
> console.log("inside then");
>     console.log(response);
>   })
>   .catch(function (error) {
> console.log("inside catch");
>     console.log(error);
>   });
> console.log("after axios");
> })
> ```

Im trying to send the defined json data to the api url when there is an entry made in a particular log file.
My console shows no error, however, the data inst reaching the api also.

Here is my log:

```
> 0|server   |
> {"@version":"1","host":"strproelk03","message":"60.16.48.61 - -
> [12/May/2020:23:24:06 -0600] \\\"GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1\\ 404 443
> 20","ApplicationName":"Oasis","Severity":"ERROR","@timestamp":"2020-05-16T20:10:39.632Z","tagfile_path":"log.log"}
> 0|server   | after axios 
> 0|server   | Watching...
```

after axios is the last message i see, it does not go inside both "inside then" or "inside cache" section of my code. Why is it not going in?

Edit: i added the timeout and bypassed my certificate validation as below:

> ```
> axios.defaults.timeout = 1000;
> const http = require('http');
> const https = require('https');
>
> const httpAgent = new http.Agent({
>     rejectUnauthorized: false,
> });
>
> const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
>     rejectUnauthorized: false,
>   });
>  axios({
>         method:'post',
>         url:url,
>         httpsAgent: httpsAgent,
>         httpAgent: httpAgent,
>         headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
>         auth: {
>             username: username,
>             password: password
>         }
> ```

Which still does not change my end result.
Still no error nor data passing.

The url is however something that works as i tested sending data directly with curl commands, which worked without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

GET /robots.txt does not exists.

You have a `Content-Type: application/json` There for your body request needs to be send as  a `JSON.stringify(json)`

```js
const Tail = require('tail').Tail;
const axios = require("axios");

exports.myFunction = function myFunction () {    

    console.log("Watching...");
    var tail = new Tail("./nxerror.log");
    tail.watch()
    tail.on("line", data => {
    console.log("data changeed");
      console.log(data);
    var username = 'Eve'
    var password = 'changeme'

    const body = {"action":"EventsRouter", "method":"add_event", "data": [{"summary":"test","device":"test","message":"msg","component":"testhost","severity":"5","evclasskey":"nxlog","evclass":"/nxlog/perf","monitor":"localhost"}],"type":"rpc","tid":2}

    var url = 'https://myurl.com/zport/dmd/evconsole_router';
    var api = axios.create();

   return api.request({
            method:'post',
            url:url,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            data: JSON.stringify(body),
            auth: {
                username: username,
                password: password
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
    console.log("inside then");
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("inside catch");
        console.log(error);
      });
    console.log("after axios");
    })
}
```

Comment: The GET message is actually the entry in the log that im reading, it is not sent anywhere. its just on the console to check if the entries are getting added. I have however added the stringify, and I have no changes in my issue.

Comment: This does not pass the data to the console itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually straightforward to verify it; you just need to replace the existing URL with a test endpoint like this: https://postman-echo.com/post and then you can see that either you receive an error or your receive a valid response. My assumption is that your request cannot be reached to the server and because the timeout for Axios is not set then Axios is just waiting. Have you tried to access the endpoint via postman?

Comment: Seems like a fair point , i set a timeout, and i received a certification error first, i bypassed it, and now its back to the same square, no error nor no data sent.

Comment: so, means something else is missing. Can you check the log on the other API to see if you receive any requests on that server?